# Viewing differences of more than than one pair of files using vimdiff

Tags: vim, diff, vimdiff

vimdiff shows differences between two or more of same files. Is it possible to see differences of two pairs of files. For eg, when viewing differenes in `.H` files and `.C` file, it will be convenient to go back and forth to see the differences. One way is to open `old.C` `new.C` `old.H` `new.H` using vim and then splitting them and running `:diffthis` in each buffer. Is there a better way?

Comment: I've only used :diffthis with 2 files. Don't know a better way.

Comment: There are good solutions in the question and in Ingo Karkat's answer, but I just have to mention a less sophisticated alternative: open vim in two windows, using vimdiff separately in each for the two pairs of files.  If you're using vim in a terminal, you'll need two terminal windows.  There are also graphical versions of vim that can open different windows directly, but that might depend on your operating system and whether you've installed a graphical version of vim.  (Ditto for neovim.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `vimdiff`, it'll diff all passed files together. To get pairwise diffing, pass and arrange the pairs in separate tab pages:

```
vim -c "edit old.C" -c "diffsplit new.C" -c "tabedit old.H" -c "diffsplit new.H"
```

If you do this often, you can write an alias / script wrapper for it.

Comment: After a decade, https://github.com/balki/vimtabdiff :)